# Magento Shopping Cart Price Rules

Tags: magento, cart, magento-rules

Out of curiosity, I am posting this question here.

Can anyone please shed some knowledge on whats the difference under **Shopping Cart Rule** for **Condtions vs Actions**

I can make any rule using actions so whats the use of Conditions and in which situations to use it ?

**Moreover If I create a Rule having coupon code and amount and use Action in it, can I show that coupon code on my product details page ?**

Answer (score 0):

```
Condition = What are the condition to enable the rules
```

and

```
Action = On which product do you apply the rules.
```

Example if you're rules is productA get 10% discount

Condition = no condition, this rule always apply

Action = 10% if SKU is productA

Example 2 if you're rule is productA get 10% only if you have at least 3 productB in your cart

Condition = quantity in the cart of productB is greater than 2

Action = 10% is SKU is productA

Discount will only get applied on productA, but there is a condition to have this discount applied (have 3 productB or more in your cart).